# Alternate visuals when catching

Tags: pokemon-go

Have you noticed the different responses when catching Pokémon?  Most of the time there is a ring that shoots out. Sometimes however there are fiery wisps that go up from the Pokémon.

Any idea what this means?

Comment: In any of these cases, does the pokeball shake once instead of 3 times?

Answer (score 9):

The animation with fiery wisps going up is the **critical catch** animation. In this case, the Ball will have shaken only **once**. A critical catch increases the chances of catching a Pokemon substantially, but has no other effect.

The ring going out with 3 stars flying outwards is the **normal catch** animation. In this case, the Ball will have shaken **three times**.

**Any other** animations, including the Ball only shaking once without the wisps or no animation at all (just the *"Great!"*), are **visual errors** caused by connectivity issues.