# What are the conditions to make a 100% catch?

Tags: pokemon-go

The last days (since gen3 is out) it happened a few times to me, that I used a superberry AND a hyperball on a basic pokemon and I immediately catched it without the ball even wobbling around.

Now I'm curious what actually caused this? was it the combination of hyper ball and superberry? would have one of the two been sufficient?

And I couldn't imagine this works for any pokemon, so if are some excluded, what are the requirements for a pokemon to be instant catchable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Alternate visuals when catching](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/304676/alternate-visuals-when-catching)

Comment: That question asks what the thing you're describing IS, while [this one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/300870/162442) asks what the odds are. I can't mark it as a dupe of the second, since there isn't an answer though.

Comment: @Vemonus: I aggree. I dissaggre with this beeing a duplicate of the first one. But indeed it is a dup of ur second comment. Maybe we should link this one still to the second instead, despite it has no usefull answer, it might guide a tiny bit more attention to that post, and a tiny bit more negative response to that answer, so it might at somepoint remove that answer showing even more clear it hasnt been answered yet. Would feel beter with that then with duping the first. But would like to hear others opinions about it, as its tough.

Comment: FYI, the english terms are "Ultraball" and "Golden Raspberry".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Critical Catch has not been sufficiently studied to be understood in Pokémon Go as  of yet.  The Silph Road (the main "research" group) hasn't determined it yet, largely because it's very hard to study (being rare, and thus highly subject to observational and reporting bias).

In general, it is thought to be unrelated to the ball, berry, etc., and instead is likely simply random.  It's possible, though, that it has some other element (such as number of Pokémon registered in the Pokédex, as it does in the main game).

It definitely does work on all Pokémon, including Legendaries and other raid bosses (I've caught a few that way).  Early on, when there was a bug that caused the "last ball" to always fail, it was still possible to succeed on a critical catch - I caught one on such a ball, as did others - which gave some slight window into the process (clearly it does "skip" some steps of capture, wherever the last-ball bug was located).